# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' - Python , BeautifulSoup Error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I just started a python web course and I was trying to parse HTML Data using BeautifulSoup and I came across this error . I researched but couldnt find any precise and certain solution . So here is the piece of code :

```
   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

   request = requests.get("http://www.johnlewis.com/toms-berkley-slipper-grey/p3061099")
   content = request.content
   soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
   element = soup.find(" span", {"itemprop ": "price ", "class": "now-price"})
   string_price = (element.text.strip())
   print(int(string_price))


  # <span itemprop="price" class="now-price"> £40.00 </span>
```

And this is the error I face :

```
   C:\Users\IngeniousAmbivert\venv\Scripts\python.exe 

   C:/Users/IngeniousAmbivert/PycharmProjects/FullStack/price-eg/src/app.py

    Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "C:/Users/IngeniousAmbivert/PycharmProjects/FullStack/price-eg/src/app.py", line 8, in <module>
             string_price = (element.text.strip())
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the *extra space characters* you have inside the tag name, attribute name and attribute values, replace:

```
element = soup.find(" span", {"itemprop ": "price ", "class": "now-price"})
```

with:

```
element = soup.find("span", {"itemprop": "price", "class": "now-price"})
```

---

After that, two more things to fix when converting the string:

- strip the `£` character from the left
- use `float()` instead of `int()`

Fixed version:

```
element = soup.find("span", {"itemprop": "price", "class": "now-price"})
string_price = (element.get_text(strip=True).lstrip("£"))
print(float(string_price))
```

You would see `40.00` printed.

Comment: Thanks mate . It worked well . But If you could elaborate the code that'd be great . Because as I mentioned I a newbie to python and I couldnt comprehend this statement :string_price = (element.get_text(strip=True).lstrip("£")) . Thanks

Comment: @user7338971 absolutely. The `.get_text(strip=True)` helps to get the text of an element and strip all the extra newlines and whitespaces around the text - normally you would do it via `.strip()`, but bs4 has this `get_text()` method which accepts a `strip` argument - quite handy. After that we left-strip the pound sign. Hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: I am really grateful . Thanks for your help . I appreciate it .

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also using css selector:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("http://www.johnlewis.com/toms-berkley-slipper-grey/p3061099")
content = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
# print soup
element = soup.select("div p.price span.now-price")[0]
print element
string_price = (element.text.strip())
print(int(float(string_price[1:])))
```

Output:

```
<span class="now-price" itemprop="price">
                                            £40.00
                                                </span>
40
```